# Bug in DSolve when solving a system of two second order PDEs?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, bugs, symbolic

**This bug has been fixed in version 12.2.0**

---

I'm solving a simple system of PDEs in Mathematica 11.1:

```
DSolve[{D[f[x, y], x, y] == 0, D[g[x, y], x, y] == 0}, {f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, y}]
```

This gives:

```
{{f[x, y] -> C[1][x] + C[2][y], g[x, y] -> C[1][x] + C[2][y]}}
```

I expect the general solution to be:

```
{{f[x, y] -> C[1][x] + C[2][y], g[x, y] -> C[3][x] + C[4][y]}}
```

What do you think?

Thanks!

Comment: Of course, this is a bug. And a very old one. I see it in versions 5.2 and 8.0.4 of Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

Fyi, bug fixed since V 12.2

[image]

Compare to

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1YoZ.png]

Answer (score -2):

[GeneratedParameters](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeneratedParameters.html) should resolve Your problem. GeneratedParameters is an option to such functions as DSolve, RSolve, and Reduce.

Comment: `GeneratedParameters` only changes the `C` to the provided name... not the numbers.
From the help: "is an option that specifies how parameters generated to represent the results of various symbolic operations should be named."
My issue is with the numbering of the parameters: I expect 4 different parameters and not only 2 as provided by `DSolve`

Comment: It is clear that the answer should be f[x,y]==f1[x]+f2[y] and g[x,y]=g1[x]+g2[y]. And certainly fi needs not be equal to gi. So, this is a bug. Please send a message to "support@wolfrom.com"